# Difference between this.variable and variable in Java

Tags: java

I don't understand the real difference between this two codes, despite the fact that they both work.

If I use this class:

```
public class City {
    private String name;
```

I don't understand the difference between this method:

```
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
```

And this one:

```
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

The two methods work, but which one is the best to use, and why do they both work?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: The only time the two are different is when there is a parameter or local variable named `name`, in which case the `this` overides the rule that a reference binds to its closest definition.

Comment: DupeChainOfDeath in action. This question shows up first on the SO search, but it is marked with a dupe of a dupe. Answers spread thin over several discussions.

Answer (score 16):

The two methods are the same in *most*, but not all cases. Take the following constructor:

```
public City(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

There is a `name` field, and a `name` in local scope. Without `this`, the one in the local scope is implicitly used (right side of assignment) but with `this` we specifically refer to the field (left side of assignment). Before the assignment shown in the example I give, `this.name` would have the default value of `null` (assuming it was declared `String name`) while `name` would be the constructor parameter's value.

This is called *shadowing* and discussed formally in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#d5e8778).

Answer (score 9):

"this" indicates the instance of the class.

In the following example, "this.a" is the a defined in the class (=10).
While "a" (=20) is the local variable, defined in the constructor.

More details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Example:

```
public class Test
{
    int a = 10;
    public Test()
    {
        int a = 20;
        System.out.println(a); // prints 20
        System.out.println(this.a); // prints the "a" defined in the class. In this case, 10
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example there is no difference.  You're just choosing to be explict about the variable being a class variable.  However if you did this:

```
public String getName(){
    String name = "David";
    return this.name;
}
```

It would mean a lot, because you're not returning the local variable named `name`, you're returning the class variable.