# Java use var value from a different method that is called in a different class

Tags: java, methods

Im making a game, and my problem is that I want to load all my assets in one method and that method be called in a different class.

This is my weapon `loadAssets()` method.

```
public void loadAssets() {
     BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
     MP5Sprite = loader.loadImage("/img/weapons/Sprite001.png");

     SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(MP5Sprite);
     MP5Side = ss.grabImage(0, 0, 27, 10);
     MP5Top = ss.grabImage(32, 0, 3, 28);
}
```

These variables are declared at the start of my class, but values only made in this method.

I want to call this in my main game class, at the start when everything is loading like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < com.main.engine.Handler.object.size(); i++) {
    GameObject tempObject = com.main.engine.Handler.object.get(i);
    tempObject.loadAssets();
}
```

This is how I am calling the method in my main game class, but because I'm not calling it in the weapon class it won't let me use those variables with the values I gave them, If it is not possible I can figure out another solution, but if it is that would be great.

I want to load everything at the start because of more images/sounds which before would only be loaded when the entity is added into the game/world, e.g. its assets are only loaded when that entity is spawned. As I would load all of the assets in the main method of each class.

Comment: You need a tutorial or teacher about variables, object, classes and methods.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to put everything that is in loadAssets() inside a static block if it has to be done only once, that is during initialisation phase.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution can be using `this.localvariable` here i make an example of your code:

```
public void loadAssets() {
     BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
     this.MP5Sprite = loader.loadImage("/img/weapons/Sprite001.png");

     SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(this.MP5Sprite);
     this.MP5Side = ss.grabImage(0, 0, 27, 10);
     this.MP5Top = ss.grabImage(32, 0, 3, 28);
}
```

This can helpyou understand **this**: [Difference between this.variable and variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529028/difference-between-this-variable-and-variable-in-java)